# Get the count of checkboxes checked in a List using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a multiple Input Checkbox List and I want to create a JS function that when the user selects more than specified count items in the checkbox list, it will reject the action but if they have fewer, it will do another function.

Need to know how to get the number of elements selected using Javascript, I'm having a really tough time doing this.

Comment: Please include the [mcve] code you’re working with, that way we can answer your question usefully, and practically. It also helps others learn from this question, and its answers, in future.

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the selected checkboxes length using the `querySelectorAll` method with the selector `input[type=checkbox]:checked`.

[Refer this](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) wonderful explanation on handling events on multiple elements in a single event listener.

```js
document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    var elem = event.target;
    if(elem.tagName=="INPUT" && elem.type=="checkbox")
    {
        var max = 3, count = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        if(count>max) event.preventDefault();
    }
});

function checkCount()
{
    
    
    if(count<=max) console.log("Selected");
    else console.log("Limit already reached");
    
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. How do I take it one step further and prevent from checking anything after the limit has been reached? Is there a way to "uncheck" when they click on the 11th element?

Comment: Yeah. You have to check the count on each click. If it is greater than the specified count, then prevent the default action. Updated my answer with the same. @Zeusftw

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of your checkboxes and iterate thru them and count the checked ones. In the code 'input' is  in your HTML. If you have this number, you can handle the actions based on it.

```
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    let countOfChecked = 0;
    checkboxes.forEach(element => {
        if (element.checked) {
            countOfChecked++;
        }
    });

if (countOfChecked > 10){
  // reject that action...
} else {
  // do your stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

**VanillaJS**

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
let limit = 2;
let countSelected = 0;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(el, i){

    el.addEventListener('click', function(){

  countSelected = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;

    if(countSelected > limit){
        el.checked = false;
      // do something... like alert: u can not select more than 10 itens
    }else{
        // do something... like change color of text
    }

  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjd8pa49/22/

**Jquery**

```
let inputs = $('input[type=checkbox]');
let limit = 2;
let countSelected = 0;

inputs.on('change', function() {

    countSelected = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

   if(countSelected.length > limit) {
        this.checked = false;
      // do something... like alert: u can not select more than 10 itens
    }else{
        // do something... like change color of text
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ezpk9cL/3/

Whenever you need to find the amount of checkboxes selected, use the css `checked` pseudo-selector.
[Checked Pseudo Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)